postfix increment ++ compiler bug on Visual Studio 2022 ARM Preview?
I would like opinions on what I suspect is a potential compiler bug, when using a postfix increment operator in a if statement.
Minimal code below:
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using IntVector = std::vector<int>;


std::pair<IntVector, IntVector> my_unweave(const IntVector& xs)
{
    std::pair<IntVector, IntVector> result;
    std::size_t counter = 0;
    for (const auto& x : xs) 
    {
        if (counter++ % 2 == 0)           // This line will fail with MSVC 2022 Preview for ARM
        {                                // It will output OOODD / EEEVEN / OOODD / EEEVEN
            printf("EEEVEN\n");          // (the postfix ++ fails...)
            result.first.push_back(x);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("OOODD\n");        
            result.second.push_back(x);
        }

        // Placing ++counter here instead of in the if test would solve the issue
        // ++counter;
    }
    return result;
}

void foo(const IntVector& xs)
{
    // This version works however
    std::size_t counter = 0;
    for (const auto& x : xs)
    {
        if (counter++ % 2 == 0)
            printf("Even\n");
        else
            printf("Odd\n");
    }
}


int main()
{
    foo(IntVector({ 0, 1, 2, 3 }));

     auto u = my_unweave(IntVector({ 0, 1, 2, 3 }));

}


will print:
Even                // foo() works
Odd
Even
Odd
OOODD                // but in my_unweave() we have an inversion
EEEVEN               // (it starts with "OOODD")
OOODD
EEEVEN

I suspect that the line
if (counter++% 2 == 0)

is where it fails.
This is a very rare occurrence and it fails only with *Visual Studio 2022 ARM Preview" (Version 17.4.0 Preview 5.0). What's more it fails only in release builds and not in debug builds.
So my question is: is that a compiler bug or is this use of the postfix increment operator likely to be a UB?

When you see the impossible happen, your first thought shouldn't be "I have a compiler bug", it should be "I have undefined behavior I can't see".  I don't see it yet myself, but that's where I'd put my money.

My bet is on a  compiler optimization bug, since it happens only in release builds, and only on this given compiler / target arch.

I'm suspicious of the same line you called out, specifically I doubt there is a sequence point that defines the order of counter++ and operator% in your example. Re-reading this to confirm https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

If you have a Preview version of the compiler, surely the odds for a compiler bug is slightly higher.

I do not think a sequence point is needed.  counter++ must get resolved before the call to operator % since it is the value that get moduloed.  From Cory's link: The value computations (but not the side effects) of the operands to any operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator (but not its side effects). seems to back that up.  We don't care about the side affects so that isn't an issue.

@NathanOliver I agree with you.  The whole point of post-increment is that the pre-incremented value is supposed to be used in the expression.  If it isn't working that way, it would indeed be a bug.

Regarding "only in release builds on this compiler", that's a very typical scenario for flushing out undefined behavior.  The compiler makes some non-obvious optimization based on undefined behavior somewhere in the code, perhaps even far from the point where you see the effect.  See Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest) for some amusing examples.

For what it's worth, I believe the behavior is well-defined, and it does look to me like a compiler bug. The expression in the if statement is little different from the classic code-golf implementation of strcpy as while (*p++ = *q++); which was around for ages (it might have appeared in K&R book) and which I don't think anyone doubts is valid.
